# Java: Matrix rotation in 2D not working

Tags: java, matrix, rotation, transformation

I have this 3x3 matrix which I'm using to preform basic transformations like translation, scaling and rotation, but the rotation part isn't working as it should. For any angle larger then 30 degrees or so, it just looks.. wierd.

The method looks like this:

```
public void rotate(float angle) {
    double rads = angle * (Math.PI/180);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(rads);
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(rads);

    matrix[0][0] = cos;
    matrix[0][1] = -sin;
    matrix[1][0] = sin;
    matrix[1][1] = cos; 
}
```

And the methods applying the transformation:

For X:

```
public float[] applyTransformX(float[] x, float[] y) {
    float[] transformed = new float[x.length];
    for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        transformed[i] = (x[i] * matrix[0][0]) + (y[i] * matrix[0][1] + matrix[0][2]);
        System.out.println((x[i] * matrix[0][0]) + (y[i] * matrix[0][1] + matrix[0][2]));

    }
    return transformed;
}
```

For Y:

```
public float[] applyTransformY(float[] x, float[] y) {
    float[] transformed = new float[x.length];
    for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        transformed[i] = (x[i] * matrix[1][0]) + (y[i] * matrix[1][1] + matrix[1][2]);
    }
    return transformed;
}
```

Are there any fundamental things I'm missing here? I'm aware of the fact that I'm not doing the transformations around a fixed point. Is that perhaps why I'm experiencing this problem?

As I said, the translation and scaling is working as it should.

Comment: is this one of those cases where you need to translate to the origin, then rotate, then translate back?  (instead of rotating the number 3 upside-down at the 3 o'clock position, you've rotated the number 3 around the clock to the 9 o'clock position?)

Comment: @JohnGardner: No, each transformation is currently running isolated.

Comment: What's the data type of `matrix`?

Comment: @DavidWallace: float[][] matrix = new float[3][3];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that I can think of is that there might be a rounding error resulting from a discrepancy in the sizes of the three terms that you're adding to get each `x[i]`, and to get each `y[i]`.  My instinct would be to add in the translation term last, so that a sizable translation doesn't cause loss of significance in the terms that result from rotation.  This just requires you removing some of your parentheses, so that the standard left-to-right order of operations kicks in.  In other words, in the method for calculating the X values, write:

```
transformed[i] = x[i] * matrix[0][0] + y[i] * matrix[0][1] + matrix[0][2];
```

without any of the parentheses.  Similarly, when calculating the Y values, write

```
transformed[i] = x[i] * matrix[1][0] + y[i] * matrix[1][1] + matrix[1][2];
```

If that doesn't help, then please post some actual numbers, so that we can see which calculations might be causing loss of significance.  The fact that this works OK for small angles suggests that you are seeing a rounding error, as opposed to an actual incorrect calculation method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but as far as I can see it did not have any affect. You can see the entire code here: http://www.lakaweb.com/pub/Transform.java -- Maybe you see some obvious faults. But your thought seems reasonable.

Comment: Your X values look OK.  Your Y values do not.  Are you sure that you haven't changed the `x` and `y` arrays before calling the `applyTransformY` method?  Remember that you need the original X values, not the transformed ones, in this method.

Comment: In fact, looking at your figures again, it _definitely_ looks like you're passing the transformed X values in, instead of the original X values, when you're calculating the Y values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the computation of  `transformed[i]` in both cases:
for X it should be:

```
transformed[i] = (x[i] * matrix[0][0]) + (y[i] * matrix[0][1]);
```

and for Y it should be:

```
transformed[i] = (x[i] * matrix[1][0]) + (y[i] * matrix[1][1]);
```

If you include `matrix[0][2]` and `matrix[1][2]` this would for a Z component, however those should evaluate to 0 for a rotation around the Z axis (`matrix[2][2]` would be 1 although to be complete). You probably just forgot to reinitialize them…

Comment: No, those terms are just there because he's doing a translation as well as the rotation/scaling.  The terms `matrix[0][2]` and `matrix[1][2]` are just the amount that he's translating, in each direction.